# AngularJS: Correct place for global menu provider, service or rootScope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, javascriptmvc

I'm new to AngularJS, and - since it is quite complex and the approach is new for me, I'm a bit confused.

I'm from "classic" background (server-side template languages [like Yii, django, Smarty] + some jQuery to make things a bit dynamic).

Let's say I have a menu bar (Bootstrap NavBar, or anything else)  - an element which lives *outside* of the main page *content*, like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="menubar">
    ... <!-- menu content -->
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Now I'd like to make the menu a bit dynamic, i.e add or remove some menu items inside of the controller. 
Using the server side frameworks & their templating systems, for example Yii - I'd simply have a `BaseController` class with `$menuItems` variable, and render it each time in the `menuBar`, while all the controllers would inherit from `BaseController` so they could modify items.

Also, I need a function which handles the `searchForm` located inside menu bar. Where should it live?

What is Angular way for something like this? So far I've been thinking of creating custom `service` or extending `$rootScope`.

Comment: Have you seen example app ? https://github.com/IgorMinar/foodme

Comment: @vittore thank you, I didn't knew this one. I wasn't aware I can use ng-controller along with ng-view :) Combining it with some shared service should do a trick. Make it a reply instead of comment and I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [global communication in angular module: event bus or mediator pattern/service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27356299/global-communication-in-angular-module-event-bus-or-mediator-pattern-service)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE**: I would encourage you to take a look at [John Papa's ng-demoes](https://github.com/johnpapa/ng-demos/) and [style-guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) as say second step in adopting angular.js.

Check out examples angular.js team posted recently, to show full application.

- [github.com/IgorMinar/foodme](https://github.com/IgorMinar/foodme)
- [github.com/GoogleChrome/wReader-app](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/wReader-app)
- [github.com/CaryLandholt/AngularFun](https://github.com/CaryLandholt/AngularFun)

Pay attention to the following features angular gives you

- [ngView](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.directive:ngView), [ngInclude](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude) directives
- templateUrl property of [directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)
- '=', '&','@' scope bindings in directives

I belive it is going be a good approach to have combination of a service and a directive for rendering menu the way you described it.